# Kivy-how to allow Horizontal and Vertical scrolling in TextInput?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm pretty new to Python and Kivy and want to make a simple code editor. I tried using the Kivy(.kv) file to make a good prototype:

```
<Label>:
    font_name:'Fura Code Retina Nerd Font Complete.otf'
    font_size:'18sp'
<GridLayout>:
    cols:3
    rows:1
    Label:
        text:"Bars"
        size_hint_x: None
        width: 50
    Label:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgb:0.085,0.095,0.085
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        text:"Bars-result"
        size_hint_x: None
        width: 170
    ScrollView:
        TextInput:
            font_size: '18sp'
            cursor_color: [255,255,255,1]
            background_color: (.17, .18, .17, 1)
            foreground_color:[255,255,255,1]
            font_name: 'Fura Code Retina Nerd Font Complete.otf'
            selection_color: (1,1,1,0.125)
```

You may have found out that if you vertically exceed the box you can scroll back up (However without an actual scroll bar). However the same doesn't happen in doing so horizontally, in fact we go to the next line. I want to make it scrollable in both x and y axis and having a scroll bar for both.
Thanks for any help, and if possible documentation help is also helpful (however, i get confused very fast with Kivy's documentation lol)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to adjust the width of the `TextInput` according to the length of the lines of text in it. Unfortunately, there is no simple way to dynamically adjust the width of a `TextInput` widget. Here is a hack that I think will work. Note that this uses internals of the `TextInput`, so may break if the `TextInput` code gets changes in future releases:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

Builder.load_string('''
<Label>:
    font_name:'Fura Code Retina Nerd Font Complete.otf'
    font_size:'18sp'
<GridLayout>:
    cols:3
    rows:1
    Label:
        text:"Bars"
        size_hint_x: None
        width: 50
    Label:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgb:0.085,0.095,0.085
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        text:"Bars-result"
        size_hint_x: None
        width: 170
    ScrollView:
        id:scroller
        TextInput:
            id: ti
            size_hint: (None, None)
            width: scroller.width
            height: max(self.minimum_height, scroller.height)
            font_size: '18sp'
            cursor_color: [255,255,255,1]
            background_color: (.17, .18, .17, 1)
            foreground_color:[255,255,255,1]
            font_name: 'Fura Code Retina Nerd Font Complete.otf'
            selection_color: (1,1,1,0.125)
            on_text: app.text_changed()
''')

class ScrollBothApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.grid = GridLayout()
        return self.grid

    def text_changed(self, *args):
        width_calc = self.grid.ids.scroller.width
        for line_label in self.grid.ids.ti._lines_labels:
            width_calc = max(width_calc, line_label.width + 20)   # add 20 to avoid automatically creating a new line
        self.grid.ids.ti.width = width_calc



ScrollBothApp().run()
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I was wondering how to do this for a long time and the documentation rarely had kv examples.Thanks you so much!!

Comment: Far more elegant and readable than the leading disclaimer had me expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simplified and slightly improved working solution. The key differences are

- one line input entry field which fills the one line scrollable output field
- scrolling is limited to horizontal
- overscrolling is prevented

## textinputscrolling.kv

```
<TextInputScrolling>:
    textInput: txt_input
    textOutput: txt_output
    scroller: scroll_view

    orientation: 'vertical'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        canvas.before:
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: "56dp"
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgb: [0,0,0]
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            TextInput:
                id: txt_input
                focus: True
                multiline: False
                on_text_validate: root.submitRequest() # ENTER triggers root.submitRequest()

            GridLayout:
                cols: 2
                ScrollView:
                    id: scroll_view
                    do_scroll_y: False # limiting to horizontal scrolling
                    effect_cls: "ScrollEffect" # prevents overscrolling
                    size_hint_x: 3
                    TextInput:
                        id: txt_output
                        size_hint: (None, None) # warning: if not there, scrolling not working !
                        width: scroll_view.width
                        cursor_color: [255,255,255,1]
                        background_color: (.17, .18, .17, 1)
                        foreground_color:[255,255,255,1]
                        selection_color: (1,1,1,0.125)
                        multiline: False
                        read_only: True
                        on_text: root.text_changed()
                Button:
                    id: clear_output_Button
                    text: 'Clear'
                    size_hint_x: 1
                    width: 130
                    on_press: root.clearAll()
```

## textinputscrolling.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


class TextInputScrolling(BoxLayout):
    textInput = ObjectProperty()
    scroller = ObjectProperty()
    textOutput = ObjectProperty()

    def submitRequest(self):
        self.textOutput.text = self.textInput.text

    def text_changed(self, *args):
        width_calc = self.scroller.width
        for line_label in self.textOutput._lines_labels:
            width_calc = max(width_calc, line_label.width + 20)   # add 20 to avoid automatically creating a new line
        self.textOutput.width = width_calc

    def clearAll(self):
        self.textInput.text = ''
        self.textOutput.text = ''


class TextInputScrollingApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Config.set('graphics', 'width', '200')
        Config.set('graphics', 'height', '60')
        Config.write()

        self.gui = TextInputScrolling()
        return self.gui

TextInputScrollingApp().run()
```

## Result

[image]